# ZSH prompt: path except current dir

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, prompt, oh-my-zsh

Can zsh set the prompt to the whole path *except* the current dir? I.e. for `~/a/b/c/` to just `~/a/b/`?

I'm trying to get this result for `~/a/b/c` with left & right prompts:

`c/: |                  ~/a/b/`

as opposed to my current duplicated `c`:

`c/: |                ~/a/b/c/`

The duplication wastes space if the `c` dir name is long.

In the [manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state) I found everything else than what i want:

- `%-1~` - the first element of the path
- `%1~` - the last element of the path

instead of all except the last

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
# Before printing each prompt string, apply substitutions to it.
setopt promptsubst

# $PWD is always equal to the present working dir.
# :h chops off the last item of the path.
# (D) substitutes the start of the path with a named dir, such as ~, if possible.
# Note that this string is in 'single quotes'!
RPS1='${(D)PWD:h}'
```

Ta-da!

Documentation:

- [`setopt promptsubst`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPTSUBST)
- [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)
- [expansion modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)